# jsf/xhtml page is being called MULTIPLE times

Tags: java, maven, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

I am doing a university work, i need to do a simple login system that reject direct URL access to some pages if there is no login, i tried to use a filter, but when i load any page, the filter is called at least 20 times, and then is called more times, if i let it be, in 30 seconds is called 80 times because it wants, i need help please, here is my code.

The filter

```
package edu.eci.pdsw.misc;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import edu.eci.pdsw.view.LoginBean;

public class LoginFilter implements Filter {


public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain     chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Get the loginBean from session attribute
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(LoginBean.mas()));
    boolean loggedIn = (session != null) && (session.getAttribute("user") != null);

        if (!loggedIn) {
            String contextPath = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getContextPath();

            ((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect(contextPath + "/Inicio.xhtml");

        }
        chain.doFilter(request,response);



}

public void init(FilterConfig config) throws ServletException {}

public void destroy() {} 

}
```

the web.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Development</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>omega</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!-- Login filter -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>edu.eci.pdsw.misc.LoginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>LoginFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/Inicio.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>edu.eci.pdsw.guice.GuiceContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

if anything else is needed please tell i will put it here, thank you for the help

Comment: Hi, it did not occur to you to log and mention to us for which url's it was called? And if it is 'looping' or whatever...? Btw, the filter and FacesServlet have different configs, is thst intentional?

Comment: Your filter is redirecting to `/yourContextPath/Inicio.xhtml` while your welcome-file is `/yourContextPath/faces/Inicio.xhtml`

Comment: As long as no user is logged in, you are redirecting from any `*.xhtml` to `Inicio.xhtml` which also is a `*.xhtml`. This must result in a loop. In your filter source code or configuration you should add (not throw) an exception to not check for login and redirect if your welcome file or other public resources are being requested.